# How can I check if a DB column exists or not when my query is stored in an XML file?

Tags: c++, sql, xml, database, c++builder

I'm working on a project with C++Builder.  I need to create a program that allows the user to check if the structure of a database (Firebird or SQL Server) is good or bad.

I have many XML files for Firebird, and I have many XML files for SQL Server. In those files there are many SQL queries defined.

The idea that I want to implement is to execute every query with `ExecSQL()`. If there are any problems in the structure of a table, `ExecSQL()` would throw an exception with all the details of the error, and I just have to take all the error messages and generate a report PDF.

The types of queries that I have in the XML files are `ALTER`, `INSERT`, and `CREATE`.

When executing a `CREATE`, if the table does not exist I can execute the query, but if the table does exist and there is a column that does not exist, the error that I get from `ExecSQL()` only tells me the table exists but does not tell me the column is missing.

For exmple, if I have this SQL code:

```sql
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(ID INT NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL);
```

After connecting to the database and executing the query, there are 3 cases:

- if the table doesn't exist, `ExecSQL()` runs without problem.
- if the table exists and all the columns that I need to create already exist, the exception that I get is `"TABLE ALREADY EXIST"`.
- if the table exists and one or more columns do not exist, the exception that I get is `"TABLE ALREADY EXIST"`. It's not telling me about the column(s).

Comment: Why not just examine the database structure metadata directly instead of executing queries that attempt to modify the database?  You can retrieve the metadata using SQL statements against the database's various system tables (like `RDB$FIELDS` in Firebird, and `sys.tables` and `sys.columns` in SQLServer), or your chosen database component likely has methods for retrieving the metadata.

Comment: Think you Remy for your reply but i don't see what you want to say exactly.

Comment: the structure of the database is described in its system tables. If you want to check if a given table or column exists, just ask the system tables using a `SELECT` statement. Don't use a `CREATE` statement. You can even query if a column's data type and attributes are what you need, or if indexes/constraints exist, etc. There is a lot of metadata you can access.